# How to project IObservable into a list of elements grouped by key in Rx?

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Given an `IObservable(Of T)` how can we transform it to an `IObservable(Of List(Of T))` that emits a list of which elements are grouped by some key ?
Using `GroupBy` , `Select` and `Scan` operator i've managed to partition the source into observable's that produces lists of all elements for each key. I don't know how to further concatenate those lists into a single one.

```
    Dim source = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.ToObservable()

    Dim keySelector = Function(element As Integer) As Integer
                          Return element Mod 3
                      End Function

    Dim result = source.GroupBy(Of Integer)(keySelector) _
                 .Select(Function(gr)
                             Return gr.Scan(New List(Of Integer), _
                                            Function(integers, current)
                                                integers.Add(current)
                                                Return integers
                                            End Function)
                         End Function)

    result.Subscribe(Sub(gr) gr.Subscribe(Sub(lst)
                                              Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", lst))
                                          End Sub))
```

It produces the following output :

```
1
2
3
1,4
2,5
3,6
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
1,4,7,10
```

while i need it to be  :

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,4,2,3
1,4,2,5,3
1,4,2,5,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9
1,4,7,10,2,5,8,3,6,9
```

Comment: Do you want a single `List(Of T)` output for each key or do you want a series of `List(Of T)`, producing a list containing all previous values plus the latest each value as it is produced, for each key?

Comment: to me the produced output seems to be exactly what was asked for (partitions into remainder-classes modulo 3) - the expected output seems to be just sorted by the remainder

Comment: @Enigmativity - I want a single list that contains  all previous values grouped. As the  source emits a values, if it belongs to a previously  discovered group append it to the group and emit the changed list.

Comment: just adapt your `Scan` (without `GroupBy`) by sorting the `integers` before you return them - this should work for now - later you can decide to use a better data-structure than a `List` (a SortedDictionary with the remainders as the keys should do - so you sort on insert instead of sort everything each time) inside to make it more performant

Comment: @Carsten - I want to emit all the partitions as a whole, in a continuous  structure. My example with integers is perhaps not a proper one, but in my application i will use some `DTOs` and maybe an immutable structure to hold everything. +1 for your suggestion to arrange the data on  insertion.

Comment: @francezu13k50 - For all subsequent values in a group do you want the same reference for the list produced or a brand new list created? If you choose the former then you are in danger of using the list in one thread as it is modified in another.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I'm thinking to use an `ImmutableList` to address this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @francezu13k50 - then you're producing a new list for each new value.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Exactly, i'm aware of state mutation problem in concurrent environment, that's why i have mentioned ImmutableList that mutates with low overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
Dim result = _
    Observable _
        .Create(Of List(Of Integer))( _
            Function (o)
                Dim keysFound = 0
                Dim keyOrder = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
                Return _
                    source _
                        .Do( _
                            Sub (x)
                                Dim k = keySelector(x)
                                If Not keyOrder.ContainsKey(k) Then
                                    keyOrder.Add(k, keysFound)
                                    keysFound = keysFound  + 1
                                End If
                            End Sub) _                      
                        .Scan( _
                            New List(Of Integer), _
                            Function(integers, current)
                                integers.Add(current)
                                Return integers
                            End Function) _
                        .Select(Function(integers) _
                            integers.OrderBy(Function (x) _
                                keyOrder(keySelector(x))).ToList()) _
                        .Subscribe(o)
            End Function)

result.Subscribe(Sub(gr) Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", gr)))
```

I get this result:

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,4,2,3
1,4,2,5,3
1,4,2,5,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6
1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9
1,4,7,10,2,5,8,3,6,9
```

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with the `.GroupBy` operator. I've also added a response with a solution that i came up to, but i have accepted your answer as it produces the exact output form and type that i asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to my question, as it not produces the requested output type, but taking into account performance, i decided to test a new approach using @Carsten suggestion to use a `Dictionary`. My source produces values very fast and i might not need to process as values comes by, so instead i might do a `.Throttle` or a `.Sample`. Given this i collect all values for each keys into lists, and emit only a `Dictionary(Of Integer,Of IList(Of T))`. At the subcriber part, after throttling or sampling, the received dictionary is flattened.

```
    Dim source = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.ToObservable()

    Dim keySelector = Function(element As Integer) As Integer
                          Return element Mod 3
                      End Function

    Dim result = source.Select(Function(i)
                                   Return New With {.reminder = keySelector(i), .value = i}
                               End Function) _
                        .Scan(ImmutableDictionary(Of Integer, IImmutableList(Of Integer)).Empty, _
                              Function(accumulate, current)
                                  Dim builder = accumulate.ToBuilder()
                                  If Not builder.ContainsKey(current.reminder) Then
                                      builder.Add(current.reminder, ImmutableList(Of Integer).Empty)
                                  End If
                                  Dim currentList = builder(current.reminder)
                                  builder(current.reminder) = currentList.Add(current.value)
                                  Return builder.ToImmutable()
                              End Function)


    result.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) _
        .Subscribe(Sub(dictionary)
                       Console.WriteLine( _
                           String.Join(",", dictionary.SelectMany(Function(pair)
                                                                      Return pair.Value
                                                                  End Function)))
                   End Sub)
```

It produces this :

```
3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8
```

The funny thing is that `ImmutableDictionary(Of Tkey, TValue)` orders it's keys as they are added, while `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` does not. For now this is not really a concern.